# How to remove everything before a certain character in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have entered data into my SQL server.  I want to remove all the characters before a hyphen.  There are different amounts of characters before the "-".

For Example:

```
ABC-123
AB-424
ABCD-53214
```

I want this result:

```
123
424
53214
```

I am new to SQL Server and really need help.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Always just one hyphen?

Comment: Look at SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX. This has been answered hundreds of times around here....at least twice today alone.

Comment: @APH yes there is only one hyphen.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
right(MyColumn, len(MyColumn) - charindex('-', MyColumn))
```

`Charindex` finds the location of the hyphen, `len` finds the length of the whole string, and `right` returns the specified number of characters from the right of the string.

Answer (score 1):

may be the other way you can do it by using reverse and Char Index

```
DECLARE  @Table1 TABLE 
    (val varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (val)
VALUES
('ABC-123'),
    ('AB- 424'),
    ('ABCD-53214')
select reverse(substring(reverse(val),0,CHARINDEX('-',reverse(val)))) from @Table1
```